# Recognition of Geometric shapes for ridges

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to recognize these geometric shapes which are related to each other. For instance, looking at the image of the roof below, just by knowing the existence of the ridges in RED, I know that the ridge in BLUE should also exist (even if it is not visible in the image). If I have thousands of such labelled images, a ML model should be able to learn this as well. However, I can't figure out how to represent this problem?

[image: Original Image (Example 1)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 1)]

**Label(s) : C, Z**

[image: Original Image (Example 2)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 2)]

**Label(s) : D**

[image: Original Image (Example 3)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 3)]

**Label(s) : C, Z**

[image: Original Image (Example 4)]

[image: Label over original Image (Example 4)]

**Label(s) : E, G**

Let's call these ridges as lines, as in the 1st example, we have X and Y lines being detected by simple edge detection but not Z because it's not visible. The same way line D is not detected but lines A, B, C are, from example 2.

What I want is that I formulate a ML model that learns from the X and Y that there should be a Z and subsequently D from A, B, C.

I have a data set of such examples where ridges are labeled (the red and blue is just to distinguish, all ridges are labeled with same color).

There are some important things to keep in mind.

- The brightness of the image could vary a lot.
- The ridge could have any scale or even orientation (within reasonable limits).
- The input image is almost always very noisy.